# Install R packages of a view to home directory, but would like to install them to default system directories

Tags: r

I would like to install R packages to system directories, but I forgot to start R with `sudo`, and ran `install.views(TimeSeries)`. From the output, it seemed to install packages to `/home/t/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2`.

When I start R with `sudo`, and ran `install.packages()`. From the output, it still seemed to install packages to my home directory:

```
> install.packages("ks")
Installing package into ‘/home/t/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2’
```

Are packages by  default installed to home directories? Is that better than installing to system directories?

I wonder how I can uninstall and remove the packages installed in my home, and reinstall them in the default system directories?

There is no function `remove.views()`. There is `remove.packages()`, but how shall I call it to remove the packages in a view?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to install in system directories, you need to log as "su -", not "sudo".

Comment: Thanks!  What are some pros and cons of installing to system dirs and to home dirs? I realized that I don't have clear clues and preferences. I am using my own laptop, not others' servers. (If in latter case, I think I have no option but to install them on home dirs)

Comment: Basically, you would install packages in system directories if you want to share them between users. If there is only one user, and for security matter, it is safer to use user's directory to install libraries. Except if you know what you do as super user.

Comment: Thanks. why "If you want to install in system directories, you need to log as "su -", not "sudo"."?  What is the difference of using su and using sudo here?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35338/su-vs-sudo-s-vs-sudo-bash

Comment: Thanks. my question is how they differ here: why can `su` work here to install packages in system dir, while `sudo` can't?

Comment: As written in the link I posted, "If you say su -, your environment gets replaced with that user's login environment as well". It is not the case with "sudo", as you keep your environment.